# Why is circuit inverse not working for EfficientSU2?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, vqe

For some reason I get the following error when attempting to find the inverse of the `EfficientSU2` VQE variational form:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not reversible

My code is as follows:

```
var_form = EfficientSU2(6, entanglement="linear")
var_form_inv = var_form.inverse() # error thrown of this line
```

Is there a bug in the implementation of the `inverse` method? and if so how can I implement a working `inverse` function?

Note `qiskit.__qiskit_version__`:

```
{'qiskit-terra': '0.15.2',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.6.1',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.4.0',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.9.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.7.5',
 'qiskit': '0.21.0'}
```

Comment: Could you open an issue for that on Qiskit Terra's GitHub? That should be fixed soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EfficientSU2` is a `BlueprintCircuit` and does not populates its internal `data` field until you try to access them.

In this case, when you are calling the `inverse` function the `data` are still empty (`None`) and this is the error you are getting. It is probably a bug and should be fixed.

Nevertheless, as a workaround for now you can try:

```
var_form = EfficientSU2(6, entanglement="linear")
# build the circuit
var_form._build() 
# or just print it
print(var_form)
var_form_inv = var_form.inverse()
```

Comment: I reported this as an issue in Qiskit, since it seems like a reasonable thing to work: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/5140